# TypeError: 'MotorCollection' object is not callable in motor python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, tornado, tornado-motor

```
#!/usr/bin/python27
import tornado
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.wsgi
import motor
import json
import jsonpickle
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db = self.settings['db'] 
class ChatWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []
    ids={}
    def my_callback(result, error):
        print 'result', repr(result)
        IOLoop.instance().stop()
    def open(self):
        ChatWebSocket.clients.append(self)
        self.write_message(jsonpickle.encode(self))
    def on_message(self, message):
        def get_current_user(self):
        print(self)
        to=db.today.ensure_index()
        array=message
        data=json.loads(array)
        if  data['st']=='ty':
            for client in ChatWebSocket.clients:
                client.write_message('"me":"ty","con":'+data['whom']+' is  typing')
        elif (data['st']=='me'):
            print("ok")
        ChatWebSocket.ids[''+data['who']+'']=data['ob']
        for s in ChatWebSocket.ids:
            print(s)
        else: 
            doc={'who':data['who'],'whom':data['whom'],'mes':data['mes']}
            to.insert(doc,callback=my_callback)
            for client in ChatWebSocket.clients:
                client.write_message('"me":"ty","con":"'+data[mes]+'"')
    def on_close(self):
        ChatWebSocket.clients.remove(self)
db=motor.MotorClient().open_sync().chat 
tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/websocket', ChatWebSocket),
(r'.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler), (r'/', MainHandler)],db=db)
tornado_app.listen(5069)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I am  trying to send the websocket   object  on on_open  function to client
and it  return  the id along with object with  it,
but it says error:TypeError: 'MotorCollection' object is not callable in json.encode(self)
please help

Comment: You are trying to encode the object, which isnt encodable - why not pass a dictionary that is encodable.

Comment: how?like this  jsonpickle.encode('{a:self}')?

Comment: What values do you need?

Comment: the  problem  is i am having trouble  sending websocket object!!!!. when i  try encode('{a:'+self+'}')  how do i send json via websocket object?

Comment: ok - I think you're not understanding the core issue here. What values of the ChatWebSocket instance does the frontend code need?

Comment: i need to  send the websocket  object on webocket opening to the client,so that next time he send the message after receving websoc object on socket  open , client  sends a  unique  id along with websocket object,and then i create a  dict of id and  websocket object.

Comment: i need  a  dict of  something like this  {'uniqueid','websocketobject'} so that i  can  send  message to each  one  depending upon the  id they  send on  any message

Comment: I would adapt: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py

Comment: Ok that is not the way  i want,i  really need to send the websocket object